# How do I shrink and grow a rectangle in monogame?

Tags: monogame, rectangles

Right now I'm creating a wack-a-mole game as my assigment. But to make the game function as perfectly as possible I need to make it so that the rectangle for my mole texture grows as the mole moves up from the hole. I also need to make it so that the rectangle shrinks when the mole is moving back in the whole. Right now you're able to hit the mole under the hole when it's not all the way up. I'm using monogame for the code.

Answer (score 0):

As with all homework problems, I am hesitant to give a complete answer. Please try to understand the code and rewrite it in your own style.

Here is a possible solution using state machines:

```
//Class level variables
Vector2 AdjustStepSize;

// Place existing large mole Rectangle values:
Vector2 BasePosition; // left and top
Vector2 BaseSize; // width and height

float HoldTimerLength = 30; // Number of steps to show before shrink
int GrowSpeed = 5;  //Number of steps to grow/shrink. Adjust as needed

int GrowStep = 0;
float HoldTimer = 0;
int State = 0; // 0 = Do nothing, 1 Grow, 2 wait for holdtimer, 3 shrink


Rectangle DrawRectangle;

// Place the following code in the constructor
AdjustStepSize = BaseSize / (GrowSpeed  << 2);

//in Update:

if (State == 2)
{
   //Do collision testing
}

switch(State)
{
   case 0:
      break;
   case 1:
      if (++GrowStep == GrowSpeed) State = 2;
      break;
   case 2:
      if (--HoldTimer == 0) State = 3;
      break;
   case 3:
      if (--GrowStep == 0) State = 0;
      break;
}
var tmp = (AdjustStepSize * GrowStep + BasePosition);
DrawRectangle.Location = new Point(tmp.X,tmp.Y);
tmp = (BaseSize - AdjustStepSize * GrowStep);
DrawRectangle.Size = new Point(tmp.X,tmp.Y);


// new method, Called when the mole should pop-up
public void Pop()
{
   HoldTimer = HoldTimerLength; // reset timer
   State = 1;
}

// draw using DrawRectangle
```

Copying and pasting without attribution will violate the "SA" clause of the [license](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).